# Reading an array<Byte> in unmanaged c++

Tags: c++, arrays, unmanaged, command-line-interface, managed

I have a managed C++ class, with a method whose constructor signature is:

```
tools_package_net::PackageInfo::PackageInfo(array<Byte>^ bytes)
```

Within the constructor I wish to call a method on an unmanaged class with the signature:

```
bool PackageInformation::ReadProject(const unsigned char *data, size_t size)
```

So I want to call "ReadProject", passing in the data from my "bytes" array.  The "size" I can pass using "bytes.Length".  But how can I get the data itself?  Can I simply typecast the first element &bytes[0] (ala std::vector)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cli::pin_ptr<unsigned char> pb = &(bytes[0]);
unsigned char* p = static_cast<unsigned char*>(pb);
```

According this [book](http://books.google.ch/books?id=wZoQyVi5f60C&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=array%3CBytes%3E%5E%20to%20native%20pointer&source=bl&ots=EgX0e4yary&sig=jAb_ZCyYL1irjOhLWYMxxY7eFOI&hl=en&ei=WFGJTs7AK4nD0QWWwM3TDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CGsQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=array%3CBytes%3E%5E%20to%20native%20pointer&f=false).